# How can I integrate Google authenticator with Kubeflow Dex authentication?

Tags: authentication, openid-connect, kubeflow, openid-dex

I have completed the kubeflow setup using the below github on top of the k3s custer I set up the kubeflow. I am working on one requirement which is when the user hit the kubeflow login url user should be able to log in via Google authenticator.

**Used git repo**:https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests#installation

Currently, I am getting UI for login which is expected

[image]

But I need to integrate the tube flow with Google authenticator. Can someone please help me with this?

Followed the below document to integrate Google authenticator but I am not getting any results.
https://dexidp.io/docs/connectors/google/

Expecting when we login the kubeflow it should redirect to google authenticator